# How to implement axon server connection check to readiness probe

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, axon, readinessprobe

I need to implement readiness and liveness probes for every microservice in my project.
In my readiness probe I need to check if our springboot application is connected to axon server.
How can I manually test if axon server is connected?

I was thinking that it is enough to add axon-spring-boot-starter dependency and it will be attached to
/actuator/health. But it did't happen.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you check the Axon documentation (https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/monitoring/health)? You might also want to take a look at a related forum thread (https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/waiting-for-axon-server-to-be-ready/2398).

Comment: Hi @David89! Did @KDW's suggestion help, or are you still looking for an answer here?